# How to delete system menu links

Tags: routes

I want to remove the "My Account" and "Log out" menu links, as I've incorporated those into other parts of the page.

Now, I'm a Drupal novice so if I'm making rookie mistakes here go easy!

What I've tried is something like this in my module.install file

```
function mymodule_enable()
{
    menu_link_delete(null, 'user');
    menu_link_delete(null, 'user/logout');
}
```

Now - that doesn't work as those two menu links are 'system' links. I tried to brute force this by creating a variant of menu_link_delete which forces deletion, by passing "true" to the $force parameter of `_menu_delete_item`...

```
function force_menu_link_delete($mlid, $path = NULL) {
    if (isset($mlid)) {
        _menu_delete_item(db_query("SELECT * FROM {menu_links} WHERE mlid = :mlid", array(':mlid' => $mlid))->fetchAssoc(), true);
    } else {
        $result = db_query("SELECT * FROM {menu_links} WHERE link_path = :link_path", array(':link_path' => $path));
        foreach ($result as $link) {
            _menu_delete_item($link, true);
        }
    }
}
```

When my module is enabled, that does successfully delete the relevant rows of the menu_link table, but by the time the Drupal has finished working its magic they have reappeared in the table!

The reason of course is that the `user_menu()` hook goes and reestablishes them. I wondered if removing them with a menu_alter hook would work...

```
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
    unset($items['user']); 
    unset($items['user/logout']); 
}
```

Sure enough, they disappear, but so does the actual capability to logout!

So - I'm going about this the wrong way. I'm guessing I shouldn't try to delete the menu links themselves, but somehow prevent my theme from displaying them.

Pointers are very welcome....

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Not sure if this is the correct approach, but it worked - I used a menu_alter hook to move the menu items to a different menu.

```
function mymodule_menu_alter(&$items) {
    $items['user']['menu_name'] = 'unused-menu';
    $items['user/logout']['menu_name'] = 'unused-menu';
}
```

Comment: That'll do it :)